# how to delete items in dictionary using pop

Tags: python, list

in my dictionary there is nim,name,gender and I want to delete 1 item by inputting his nim

```
elif (menu == 3):
    hapus = input("Masukan NIM Yang Ingin Dihapus: ")
    ada = True
    for mhs in data_semua_mhs:
        if (mhs["nim"]== hapus):
            ada = True
            mhs.pop(hapus("nim"))
    if ada is False:
        print("Data Tidak Tersedia")
```

The traceback:

```
Pilih Menu: 3
Masukan NIM Yang Ingin Dihapus: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\py lat\latihan_pertemuan_10.py", line 68, in <module>
    mhs.pop(hapus("nim"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is `hapus("nim")` supposed to do?

Comment: "hapus" is a sting you inputted. You can't call a string like a function. Search if you have another defined "hapus".

Comment: Stackoverflow uses English as its official language. It would make it easier on the responders if you named your variables in English (and it's a good practice even outside of Stackoverflow)

Comment: @Marko - ["Variables and the like can be written in any language. A code snippet containing non-English variables that can easily be followed does not require flagging or editing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/1324033)

Comment: Are you trying to delete the name from the person, or are you trying to remove the person from the list of people?

Comment: @Sayse - I stand corrected. Thank you. I would still recommend to the OP to start using English variables in his day to day coding.

Comment: @Marko sorry this is the first time I asked in the stackoverflow next I'll use English in my script,Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the person from the list of people, try:

```
elif (menu == 3):
    hapus = input("Masukan NIM Yang Ingin Dihapus: ")
    ada = True
    for mhs in range(len(data_semua_mhs)):
        if (data_semua_mhs[mhs]["nim"]== hapus):
            ada = True
            data_semua_mhs.pop(mhs)
            break
    if ada is False:
        print("Data Tidak Tersedia")
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem is that `hapus` is a string (it's whatever the user typed in the console), and you're trying to call it like a function `hapus("nim")`, but strings can't be called like functions.

I think you probably want `mhs.pop(hapus)` (or equivalently `mhs.pop(mhs["nim"])`, since they're equal in that branch).